# Java how to get specific line and its number

Tags: java

So i am making a program which gets data from a text file , for a reason which i cant say i cannot use db.

Code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Points {

   public void ReadFile() throws IOException {
       int lineNumber = 0;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner("test.txt");

       while(scan.hasNextLine())
       {
           lineNumber++;
           scan.nextLine();
           if(scan.nextLine().startsWith("12345"))
           {
               break;
           }
       }

       String specific_line_text = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("bal.txt")).get(lineNumber);

       System.out.println(specific_line_text);
   }

}
```

Sample Text File (note : The Numbers are in the line)

```
1 random line 1
12 random line 3
123 random line 6
1234 random line 10
12345 random line 15
```

there are no errors in the code but i cant get the expected result

expected result is "12345 random line 15"

Comment: And your question is what exactly?

Comment: the question is that i cannot get the line and there are no errors

Comment: scan.nextLine() returns the next line as a String. You can call scan.nextLine() to advance to the next line, but if you call it again in your if condition you are skipping every other line. Try storing it in a String and testing that String for your numbers instead.

Comment: Hi and welcome. To help make your question more clear, please add a sample of what your file looks like as well as the expected result. We usually can't help if we can't reproduce your issue and understand what you want. With that said, @Jems has a good suggestion to help you.

Comment: i already gave the code , i added the expectation you can check it

Comment: question is not clear. Do code using examples using w3schools, geek for geeks. So at least we can prevent syntax errors. Ask good questions otherwise, your account will not allow asking more questions like mine did once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program contains multiple bugs.

```
new Scanner("test.txt")
```

First of the the above call doesn't scan a file, rather it scans the string that you provide.

```
 scan.nextLine();
 if(scan.nextLine().startsWith("12345"))
 {
    break;
 }
```

Here you call nextLine() twice. You better call it once and assign its result to a variable.